# Issue finding the number of repetitions of a large value

Tags: python, python-3.x

This program is to find the number of repetition of the pattern 1(0's)1 Ex:1001,1001001 but getting run time error for larger value of length
Please me suggest me solution for the error

```
def patternCount(s):

    count=0

    for i in range(len(s)-1):

        if s[i]=='1':

            k=i

            while s[k+1]=='0':

                k=k+1

            if s[k+1]=='1':

                count+=1

    return count

    s = input()

    result = patternCount(s)

    print(result)
```

Comment: So, you basically just want to count the occurrences of runs of `0` in a string of `1` and `0`?

Comment: You program outputs `3` for the input `1111`. Is this intentional? I.e., are you counting groups of `0` with zero length? In this case, just output `count('1') - 1`?

Comment: No actually it should print out put for number of occurrences of pattern 1(any number of 0's )1 EX: 1001acvd00101   and is 2 , 10101jhcz01001 ans is 3 like that

Comment: What about `010` and `111`? Do zeros on the edges count, and does "any number" include "zero"?

Comment: 010 and 111 should display result 0 because of the absence of the given pattern

Comment: In this case, see my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of that complicated nested loop, you could just use existing libraries to find groups of consecutive `0` and count them, for example using `itertools.groupby`...

```
>>> s = "10001001011"
>>> sum(1 for k, g in itertools.groupby(s) if k == '0')
3
```

... or `regular expressions`:

```
>>> len(re.findall('0+', s))
3
```

Note, however, that your current program seems to also count `empty` groups of `0`, e.g. `1111` would return `3`. In this case, you could use a regular expression with `0*` and some lookbehind and lookahead:

```
>>> len(re.findall('(?<=1)0*(?=1)', s))
4
```

Or just count the number of `1` in your string and subtract `1`, which is pretty much the same as what your current function is doing, just in a slightly less convoluted way (assuming that the string has to start and end with `1`):

```
>>> s.count('1') - 1
4
```

---

Given your recent comments, the following regular expression should work: `(?<=1)0+(?=1)` This checks for groups of one or more zeros `0+`both preceded by `(?<=1)` and followed `(?=1)` by a one. Then just use re.findall`and`len` to find and count those groups.

```
>>> s = "0110010001jhcz00001000001000000"
>>> re.findall('(?<=1)0+(?=1)', s)
['00', '000', '00000']
>>> len(re.findall('(?<=1)0+(?=1)', s))
3
```